# How to Make WordPress Jetpack Top Posts Plugin to Recognize Line Breaks?

Tags: wordpress, widget, title, line-breaks, jetpack

Am using the below codes to enable line breaks in titles...

```
function line_break_for_posts_filter($title){
        return str_replace(' | ', '<br />', $title);
    }
add_filter('the_title', 'line_break_for_posts_filter');
```

However, this isn't recognized in Jetpack's Top Post widget (https://jetpack.com/support/extra-sidebar-widgets/top-posts-pages-widget/).

Perhaps I can add a custom filter specifically for this widget, but how?